# connect to a softphone from a normal mobile phone

Tags: asterisk, telephony, jtapi

Can I connect to a soft phone using Asterisk on a network, from a normal mobile phone from outside the network?

I'm desperate to know whether or not this is possible to connect to a soft phone from a PSTN connected mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for that you need have DID number registered on your asterisk server.

You can have DID via sip or iax protocol. Check google "did service provider sip".